# Setting Navbar open as Default

Tags: css

My navbar is currently closed as default (navbar only shows on mobile).

Is there some css that will default the nav bar to open?

I currently have no code as I'm trying to edit a template. I believe it's a bootstrap navbar.

Site: yodega.com (on mobile, or small screen)

Thanks!

Comment: Please include [mcve] in your post, such as example code which can show what you have already. Also, if you are using some framework (e.g. Bootstrap), please tell us, including its version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported by default:

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3944

#### There is simple and fast but not clean solution:

You can simulate clicking on navbar element after page rendering:

```
document.querySelector('button.navbar-toggle').click()
```

Method click is described in link:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

#### There is also better solution but it require to change your source code.

When your page is rendered you can find something like this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-top-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
```

You can simply change it on this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-top-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
```

Probably `style="height: 0px;"` is added by your library, and you should overwrite this behavior.